# How to check whether the clicked element is having background property using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to check whether the element i click on page is having a background property and this is the code i tried

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll('*');

img.forEach(function(image){
  image.addEventListener("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(this.style.background){
         console.log("yes");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkpb4mx3/16/)

```
window.getComputedStyle(this , null).getPropertyValue( "background-image" )
```

will do the trick

BTW, I added also a e.stopPropagation(); to prevent bubbling down the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(e.target.style.background){
  console.log("yes");
}
```